# Eclipse CDT using std libraries in external console

Tags: c++, terminal, std, eclipse-cdt

I created C++ console project in Eclipse on Windows 7. I wanted it to run in external terminal, so I configured External Tool as described here: [LINK](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/898966/). The following code runs fine and shows "Hello" on the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

void foo() {
    //queue<char> x;
}

int main() {
    //vector<int> a;
    //string t;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I uncomment one of the lines above, external console refuses to work (program exits instantly). Program compiles successfully and runs in the internal console.

The variables do not have to be used, declaration is sufficient to stop excution. I assume, there is something wrong with the External Tool, as the internal console works normally (maybe I should add some libraries to working directory).

Any ideas?